# How can I do Bluetooth testing for a P2P mobile application for multiple devices?

Tags: android, flutter, testing, bluetooth, p2p

I am making a small school project. I am developing a P2P android mobile application that will detect other similar devices(devices that are using the same app) around.
My question is how can I test it while developing? Can I somehow run 2 physical devices at the same time and then check their Bluetooth functionalities(If yes, then please link a video, article etc.)? Or is there any other solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: What problem did you face in trying to test 2 physical devices at the same time?

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) for your project?